# Heating a large main room in Central Ontario with 46' of fixed and operating windows

Tags: heating

We are doing a summer cottage into year round home reno. We will be heating with propane powered forced air furnace. We want to keep the floor to ceiling view. The heating ducts will be in front of the windows, as they are usually placed. Might it be an idea to ALSO have ceiling ducts? We are adding a second floor and there will be lots of room between the floors for extra ducting. I understand, hot air rises, but might this be a way to have a better chance of keeping the room warm in the winter? Has anyone ever seen this?

Comment: If you have enough velocity to drive it down so it mixes, above can work. Might not be pleasant or quiet, though. Anyway you slice it, your propane supplier will be making bank off your needs...especially if your 46 feet of windows are typical summer cottage windows (terrible .vs. merely lousy for heat loss.)

Comment: The windows will probably be biggest heat loss if walls are insulated well.  Can see if you can afford if needed getting better windows, but 46 feet be expensive.  Walls could also do with better insulation if this was built as summer place.  Might be looking at cost close to a new house to make it comfortable in winter, depending on quality of windows and wall/ceiling insulation.

Comment: Oh don't worry, the high ceilings will get *plenty* of heat...

Comment: There are booster fans for duct work, which probably be needed to push heat down, but think you still need to improve or prevent cold air from windows, blocking and/or insulating most of them for winter.  Air tight insulated shutters at least for night time  use, open them when sun is hitting.